# How to access wrapped variables in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have an *object* which consists of multiple *arrays*:

```
$scope.myArrays = {
    array1: ['Pizza', 'Spaghetti'],
    array2: ['Lasagne', 'Schnitzel']
};
```

Moreover, I have a custom *directive* to which I want to pass this *object* `myArrays` and **bind those arrays to scope variables**:

```
<my-directive my-data="myArrays"></my-directive>
```

---

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            arrayOne: '=myData.array1',
            arrayTwo: '=myData.array2'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            // get access to scope.array1 and scope.array2
        }
    };
});
```

[All together in a fiddle for you to play around!](http://jsfiddle.net/996xmv6h/)

Is there a way to bind the arrays directly or do I need to bind `arrays: '=myArrays'` and access them like `arrays.array1`?

Comment: You cannot do that with 2-way binding like this. Binding needs to be one-one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding has to be one to one, you cannot do that. Yes, you will have to access the arrays inside your directive.

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            myData: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem) {
           scope.arrayOne = scope.myData.array1;
           scope.arrayTwo = scope.myData.array2;
        }
    };
});
```

You can directly access `scope.myData.array1` and `scope.myDate.array2` inside the directive template if you dont have to process these arrays in the link function and get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

You **could** do this by just assigning them to `scope` fields:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            myData: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            scope.arrayOne = myData.array1;
            scope.arrayTwo = myData.array2;
        }
    };
});
```

However, I would recommeend to just bind the object and to get rid of the `link`-function. That way the directives code is a lot shorter, more readable, less "black magic" happens and the references inside the directive are more expressive:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            myData: '='
        }
    };
});
```

Then you can just reference it inside the directive with `myData.array1`. Replace the `'='` with `'=someName'` to reference it with `someName.array1`

Answer (score 0):

your HTML should be :

```
<my-directive arrayone="myData.array1" arraytwo="myData.array2"></my-directive>
```

and your directive :

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            arrayOne: '=arrayone',
            arrayTwo: '=arraytwo'
        },
        link:function(scope){
            console.log('arrayOne :',scope.arrayOne);
            console.log('arrayTwo :',scope.arrayTwo);
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            console.log('arrayOne :',$scope.arrayOne);
            console.log('arrayTwo :',$scope.arrayTwo);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: possible, but not what i am looking for. sorry

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/996xmv6h/1/)

HTML-Partial:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <my-directive my-data="myArrays" array-one="myArrays.array1" array-two="myArrays.array2">
    </my-directive>
</div>
```

Script:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            arrayOne: '=',
            arrayTwo: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            // get access to scope.array1 and scope.array2
             //console.log(scope.array1)
             console.log(scope.arrayOne); 
             console.log(scope.arrayTwo);          

        }
    };
})

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myArrays = {
        array1: ['Pizza', 'Spaghetti'],
        array2: ['Lasagne', 'Schnitzel']
    };
});
```

Comment: possible, but not what i am looking for. sorry